# Automate to Get data from SFTP to Local server in python

Tags: python

Hi There are files generated on daily basis in the form of .txt , i am currently manually downloading the files and keeping in the required folder.

From this folder MySql picks up data and do few tasks.

Can anyone help me in automating the process of lifting data from sftp to local server in Python

Comment: checkout `pysftp` or `paramiko` for python

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with *pysftp* module.
Here is simple script that downloads file from SFTP server:

```py
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='user', password='pass') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('data'):             # chdir to your directory
        sftp.get('somefile')          # get a remote file
```

More info about pysftp can be found [here](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/cookbook.html)
Provide your credentials, save this file as *sftp_backup.py* and add it to daily cron task (**crontab -e**):

```
1 0 * * * /path/to/sftp_backup.py
```

And now your data will be downloaded from SFTP server every day at 01:00 PM

Comment: In one of the other answers there is something called cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None  , what does these represent ?

Comment: _pysftp.CnOpts_ object is used to set up additional connection options. _hostkey_ option disables host key checking.